# Why $(x v_{i}, v_{j})(x w_{i^{\prime}}^{*}, w_{j^{\prime}}^{*})=((P\left(v_{i} \otimes w_{i^{\prime}}^{*}\right), v_{j} \otimes w_{j^{\prime}}^{*})$

Tags: representation-theory

When I was learning a theorem of Orthogonality of matrix elements, I faced a step I could not understand. (,) is the Hermitian inner product, P=$\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{x \in G} x $, we have
$\left(t_{i j}^{V}, t_{i^{\prime} j^{\prime}}^{W}\right)=|G|^{-1} \sum_{x \in G}\left(x v_{i}, v_{j}\right) \overline{\left(x w_{i^{\prime}}, w_{j^{\prime}}\right)}=|G|^{-1} \sum_{x \in G}\left(x v_{i}, v_{j}\right)\left(x w_{i^{\prime}}^{*}, w_{j^{\prime}}^{*}\right)=\left(P\left(v_{i} \otimes w_{i^{\prime}}^{*}\right), v_{j} \otimes w_{j^{\prime}}^{*}\right)$

I know not much about the tensor product, and I don't understand this step about the Hermitian product of tensor product.